# Installing Teamspeak via PPA

Tags: apt, teamspeak

I want to install teamspeak client on Kubuntu 16.04. Of course I could download the **.deb** file from [teamspeak.com](https://teamspeak.com/en/downloads/), but I want to update it via `apt-get`. According to this article https://help.ubuntu.com/community/TeamSpeak you can install it with `apt-get install teamspeak-client`, but it is not working (package not found).

Is there a special repository I need to add?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running?  The article you quoted is for Ubuntu 7.04 Feisty Fawn, which is pretty old.  I am going to venture to guess that if it does not work in your version of Ubuntu, it was not moved into the later versions repositories.

Comment: @ChristopherAngulo-Bertram 16.04. I didnt see, that it was for 7.04

Comment: "Since Feisty, Teamspeak client and server packages are available in the Ubuntu repositories. " I then did a search, and for no other versions does it seem that the repositories have been updated.  I have not tried this, but this looks pretty easy to install.  http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-teamspeak3-3-0-14-on-the-most-popular-linux-systems/  There might be a newer version than 3.0.14, so check on the website to see, and change the command lines in this article accordingly.

Comment: @ChristopherAngulo-Bertram: your comment seems outdated, I couldn't find any working PPA for Ubuntu 20.04. So I finally downloaded the `.run` file from https://teamspeak.com/en/downloads/